# Blackberry foreground after background

Tags: blackberry, foreground

When my app is running in background and I click its icon, it comes from background to foreground. Which function is triggered at first? I searched, after coming from background it triggers the `public void activate()` in the class which is extended by `Application`.

Now I have a GUI class, lets say Login.java, which extends `UiApplication`. What should I write in this class to see that Application has come from background to foreground?

And when going to Background I use this code

```java
    public boolean onClose() {

        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MyScreen.setBackgroundFlag("true");
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().requestBackground();
            };
        });
        //Application.getApplication().requestForeground();
        //System.exit(0); 
        return true;        
    }
```

Comment: The UiApplication class `extends Application`, so the `activate()` method works in it, too.  A `UiApplication` *is a* `Application`. [See here for more on this](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Detect-when-an-application-or-screen-moves-to-the-foreground-or/ta-p/444979)